# Akka ClusterClient Doesn't Actually Send GetContacts

Tags: .net, akka, akka.net, akka-cluster

I am running into an issue implementing the Akka Cluster Client, as it seems the ClusterClient never actually sends a GetContacts message, even though it is indicating that it is sending it (in Debug Logs).

I am confident that the message is not being sent as I am running a network capture between the box where the Server (Receptionist) is running and where the Client (ClusterClient) is running, and I see no packets on the indicated port where the ClusterClient is supposedly sending.

I have looked at all the configs numerous times, and I cannot see anything wrong, and the fact that the logs indicate the GetContacts is being sent, but nothing hits the network has me completely confused.

The Server Logs no messages or errors after it initializes and the 8092 port is listening (I see it in netstat, and I can telnet to it). It just seems that the client never actually sends a message to the Server port 8092. I have also tried running this on a localsystem using 127.0.0.1 as the Hostname for both server and client, and I see the same issue, no packets getting sent from Client process to Server process.

Here are the client logs, which includes the akka HOCON config. The GetContacts keeps repeating, and several seconds after initiation (7:46:24) the Client attempts to use the ClusterClient to send a message, however it receives "Receptionist not available, buffering message type..."

Server Logs and Code are below Client Logs and Code

## Client Debug Logs

```
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Event.EventStream 6 Default Loggers started 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Event.LoggingBus+UnhandledMessageForwarder 6 Started (Akka.Event.LoggingBus+UnhandledMessageForwarder) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Starting remoting 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/remoting-terminator 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/transports 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/endpointManager 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Remote.TransportSupervisor 6 Started (Akka.Remote.TransportSupervisor) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Starting prune timer for endpoint manager... 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Remote.EndpointManager 6 Started (Akka.Remote.EndpointManager) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider+RemotingTerminator 6 Started (Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider+RemotingTerminator) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider+RemotingTerminator 6 now watched by [akka://ClientSystem/system] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolManager 6 Started (Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolManager) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Remote.TransportSupervisor 6 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp.0 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Remoting started; listening on addresses : [akka.tcp://ClientSystem@10.20.123.42:23695] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.4991 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://ClientSystem@10.20.123.42:23695] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5191 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 5 Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClientSystem@10.20.123.42:23695] - Starting up... 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5191 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 3 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/cluster 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5301 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 3 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/clusterEventBusListener 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5452 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon 8 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5452 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon 8 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/cluster/core 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5452 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon 8 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/cluster/heartbeatReceiver 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5452 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor 6 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5452 Akka.Cluster.ClusterHeartbeatReceiver 5 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterHeartbeatReceiver) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Cluster Node [akka.tcp://ClientSystem@10.20.123.42:23695] - Started up successfully 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor 6 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/cluster/core/publisher 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor 6 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/cluster/core/daemon 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 5 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/remote-watcher 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 5 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/remote-deployment-watcher 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 21 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/deadLetterListener 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Event.EventStream 5 subscribing [akka://ClientSystem/system/deadLetterListener#1224522872] to channel Akka.Event.DeadLetter 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Event.DeadLetterListener 5 Started (Akka.Event.DeadLetterListener) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Remote.RemoteDeploymentWatcher 5 Started (Akka.Remote.RemoteDeploymentWatcher) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 19 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/EventStreamUnsubscriber-1 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Event.EventStreamUnsubscriber 21 registering unsubscriber with Akka.Event.EventStream 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5693 Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl 3 NewtonSoftJsonSerializer has been detected as a default serializer. It will be obsoleted in Akka.NET starting from version 1.5 in the favor of Hyperion (for more info visit: http://getakka.net/docs/Serialization#how-to-setup-hyperion-as-default-serializer ). If you want to suppress this message set HOCON `akka.suppress-json-serializer-warning` config flag to on. 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Event.EventStreamUnsubscriber 3 Started (Akka.Event.EventStreamUnsubscriber) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDomainEventPublisher 3 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterDomainEventPublisher) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl 3   akka : {
    log-config-on-start : on
    stdout-loglevel : DEBUG
    loglevel : DEBUG
    loggers : ["Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger, Akka.Logger.NLog"]
    actor : {
      serialize-messages : on
      serialize-creators : on
      provider : "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
      debug : {
        receive : on
        autoreceive : on
        lifecycle : on
        event-stream : on
        unhandled : on
      }
    }
    remote : {
      log-received-messages : on
      log-sent-messages : on
      enabled-transports : [akka.remote.dot-netty.tcp]
      dot-netty : {
        tcp : {
          transport-protocol : tcp
          port : 0
          hostname : 10.20.123.42
        }
      }
      log-remote-lifecycle-events : DEBUG
    }
    cluster : {
      client : {
        initial-contacts : ["akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/system/receptionist"]
      }
    }
  }

2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Actor.GuardianActor 3 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/user/ordertracker 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Event.EventStream 3 subscribing [akka://ClientSystem/system/cluster/core/daemon#1545645994] to channel Akka.Remote.QuarantinedEvent 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 3 No seed-nodes configured, manual cluster join required 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 3 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5793 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 3 now watched by [akka://ClientSystem/system/cluster/core#515725268] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5943 ClientPump.OrderTracker 5 Order Tracker Started 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5943 ClientPump.OrderTracker 19 Started (ClientPump.OrderTracker) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5943 ClientPump.OrderTracker 19 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/user/ordertracker/crouter 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5943 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 8 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.5943 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 5 Started (Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6074 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 19 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6074 Akka.Remote.EndpointManager 8 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FNGOMSCluster%4010.20.223.45%3A8092-1 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6074 Akka.Remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor 5 Started (Akka.Remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6074 Akka.Remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor 5 now watched by [akka://ClientSystem/system/endpointManager#268440055] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6074 Akka.Remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor 5 now supervising akka://ClientSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FNGOMSCluster%4010.20.223.45%3A8092-1/endpointWriter 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6074 Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter 19 Started (Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6074 Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter 19 now watched by [akka://ClientSystem/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriter-akka.tcp%3A%2F%2FNGOMSCluster%4010.20.223.45%3A8092-1#1733941078] 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6384 Akka.Cluster.ClusterRemoteWatcher 8 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterRemoteWatcher) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6384 Akka.Cluster.ClusterReadView+EventBusListener 5 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterReadView+EventBusListener) 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6384 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 19 [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6384 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 20 [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6856 Akka.Event.EventStream 6 subscribing [akka://ClientSystem/system/remote-watcher#92163059] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IMemberEvent 
2017-08-30 07:46:19.6856 Akka.Event.EventStream 4 subscribing [akka://ClientSystem/system/clusterEventBusListener#2106616419] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IClusterDomainEvent 
2017-08-30 07:46:22.6062 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 3 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:24.1453 ClientPump.OrderTracker 3 Send Order Received, will try to send to akka://ClientSystem 
2017-08-30 07:46:24.1524 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 19 Receptionist not available, buffering message type [SendToAll] 
2017-08-30 07:46:24.1524 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 6 Receptionist not available, buffering message type [Send] 
2017-08-30 07:46:24.1524 ClientPump.OrderTracker 6 received handled message ClientPump.SendOrder from akka://ClientSystem/deadLetters 
2017-08-30 07:46:25.6163 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 3 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:28.6254 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 8 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:31.6354 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 20 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:34.6464 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 4 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:37.6555 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 20 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:40.6665 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 6 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
2017-08-30 07:46:43.6764 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 21 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/), Path(/system/receptionist)]]
```

### Client Code

```
class OrderTracker : ReceiveActor, ILogReceive
{
    private static NLog.Logger log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public OrderTracker()
    {

        var settings = ClusterClientSettings.Create(Context.System);

        var clusterClient = Context.ActorOf(ClusterClient.Props(settings), "crouter");

        log.Info("Order Tracker Started");
        Receive<OrderMessage>(o =>
            {
                log.Info(o.ClientID + "," + o.OrderID.ToString() + "," + o.State.ToString() + "," + o.Side.ToString() + "," + o.Symbol + "," + o.Price.ToString() + "," + o.Quantity.ToString());
            });

        Receive<SendOrder>(o =>
            {
                log.Info("Send Order Received, will try to send to " + clusterClient.Path.Address.ToString());
                clusterClient.Tell(new ClusterClient.SendToAll("/user/manager/client", o.Message));
                clusterClient.Tell(new ClusterClient.Send("/user/manager/client", o.Message));
            });
    }
}
```

}

### Server Logs

```
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Event.LoggingBus+UnhandledMessageForwarder 6 Started (Akka.Event.LoggingBus+UnhandledMessageForwarder) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Event.EventStream 6 Default Loggers started 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/remoting-terminator 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/transports 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Starting remoting 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Remote.TransportSupervisor 6 Started (Akka.Remote.TransportSupervisor) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/endpointManager 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider+RemotingTerminator 6 Started (Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider+RemotingTerminator) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Starting prune timer for endpoint manager... 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Remote.EndpointManager 6 Started (Akka.Remote.EndpointManager) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1624 Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider+RemotingTerminator 6 now watched by [akka://NGOMSCluster/system] 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1724 Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolManager 6 Started (Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolManager) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1724 Akka.Remote.TransportSupervisor 6 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp.0 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1724 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Remoting started; listening on addresses : [akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092] 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1724 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092] 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1724 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 6 Cluster Node [akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092] - Starting up... 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1724 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1724 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 6 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/clusterEventBusListener 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1884 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon 5 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1884 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon 5 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1884 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDaemon 5 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/heartbeatReceiver 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1884 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor 5 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.1884 Akka.Cluster.ClusterHeartbeatReceiver 5 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterHeartbeatReceiver) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core/publisher 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Event.DummyClassForStringSources 7 Cluster Node [akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092] - Started up successfully 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreSupervisor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core/daemon 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Cluster.ClusterReadView+EventBusListener 7 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterReadView+EventBusListener) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/remote-watcher 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/remote-deployment-watcher 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Cluster.ClusterDomainEventPublisher 7 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterDomainEventPublisher) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Remote.RemoteDeploymentWatcher 7 Started (Akka.Remote.RemoteDeploymentWatcher) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Cluster.ClusterRemoteWatcher 4 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterRemoteWatcher) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Event.EventStream 20 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core/daemon#658632128] to channel Akka.Remote.QuarantinedEvent 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 20 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2084 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 20 now watched by [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core#1737578814] 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2194 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 20 [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2194 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 20 [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2194 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 20 [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+JoinSeedNodes 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2194 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 6 [Uninitialized] Received Akka.Cluster.ClusterUserAction+JoinTo 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2194 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/distributedPubSubMediator 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2454 Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl 7 NewtonSoftJsonSerializer has been detected as a default serializer. It will be obsoleted in Akka.NET starting from version 1.5 in the favor of Hyperion (for more info visit: http://getakka.net/docs/Serialization#how-to-setup-hyperion-as-default-serializer ). If you want to suppress this message set HOCON `akka.suppress-json-serializer-warning` config flag to on. 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Cluster.Tools.PublishSubscribe.DistributedPubSubMediator 7 Started (Akka.Cluster.Tools.PublishSubscribe.DistributedPubSubMediator) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/receptionist 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/deadLetterListener 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Actor.SystemGuardianActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/EventStreamUnsubscriber-1 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Actor.Internal.ActorSystemImpl 7   akka : {
    log-config-on-start : on
    stdout-loglevel : DEBUG
    loglevel : DEBUG
    loggers : ["Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger, Akka.Logger.NLog"]
    extensions : ["Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClientReceptionistExtensionProvider, Akka.Cluster.Tools"]
    actor : {
      serialize-creators : on
      provider : "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"
      debug : {
        receive : on
        fsm : on
        event-stream : on
        router-misconfiguration : on
        autoreceive : on
        lifecycle : on
        unhandled : on
      }
    }
    remote : {
      log-received-messages : on
      log-sent-messages : on
      enabled-transports : [akka.remote.dot-netty.tcp]
      dot-netty : {
        tcp : {
          transport-protocol : tcp
          port : 8092
          hostname : 10.20.223.45
        }
      }
      log-remote-lifecycle-events : DEBUG
    }
    cluster : {
      log-info : on
      seed-nodes : ["akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092"]
      debug : {
        verbose-heartbeat-logging : off
      }
    }
  }

2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/deadLetterListener#2069104233] to channel Akka.Event.DeadLetter 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Event.DeadLetterListener 7 Started (Akka.Event.DeadLetterListener) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Event.EventStreamUnsubscriber 7 registering unsubscriber with Akka.Event.EventStream 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Event.EventStreamUnsubscriber 7 Started (Akka.Event.EventStreamUnsubscriber) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Actor.GuardianActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/user/manager 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 NGSOMS.ManagerActor 7 Started (NGSOMS.ManagerActor) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 NGSOMS.ManagerActor 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/user/manager/client 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterReceptionist 7 Started (Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterReceptionist) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/clusterEventBusListener#1987664108] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IClusterDomainEvent 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/remote-watcher#420721983] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IMemberEvent 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 NGSOMS.ClientActor 7 Receive Actor has moved to Ready 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 NGSOMS.ClientActor 7 Client Ref is akka://NGOMSCluster/user/manager/client 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 NGSOMS.ClientActor 7 Client Actor Starting ... 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 NGSOMS.ClientActor 7 Started (NGSOMS.ClientActor) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 NGSOMS.ClientActor 7 now watched by [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/distributedPubSubMediator#796287490] 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Cluster.ClusterHeartbeatSender 7 Started (Akka.Cluster.ClusterHeartbeatSender) 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2524 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 7 Node [akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092] is JOINING, roles [] 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2804 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 5 Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092] to [Up] 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 7 now supervising akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core/daemon/heartbeatSender 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 21 [Initialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 21 [Initialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 21 [Initialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Cluster.ClusterCoreDaemon 21 [Initialized] Received Akka.Cluster.InternalClusterAction+Subscribe 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/distributedPubSubMediator#796287490] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IMemberEvent 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/user/manager#1738083469] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+MemberUp 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/receptionist#1611611694] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IMemberEvent 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core/daemon/heartbeatSender#1833894805] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IMemberEvent 
2017-08-30 07:44:48.2814 Akka.Event.EventStream 7 subscribing [akka://NGOMSCluster/system/cluster/core/daemon/heartbeatSender#1833894805] to channel Akka.Cluster.ClusterEvent+IReachabilityEvent
```

### Server Code - Creating /manager Actor

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var system = ActorSystem.Create("NGOMSCluster");

    ActorSystemRefs.ManagerActor = system.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ManagerActor()), "manager");

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

### Server Code - Creating /manager/client Actor

```
class ManagerActor : UntypedActor, IWithUnboundedStash
{
    private readonly ILoggingAdapter _log = Logging.GetLogger(Context);
    private IActorRef _clientActor;
    private IActorRef _exchangeActor;
    protected Akka.Cluster.Cluster Cluster = Akka.Cluster.Cluster.Get(Context.System);
    protected Dictionary<long, OrderMessage> masterOrderList;
    protected Dictionary<long, OrderTrack> orderTracking;

    /// <summary>
    /// Need to subscribe to cluster changes
    /// </summary>
    protected override void PreStart()
    {
        Cluster.Subscribe(Self, new[] { typeof(ClusterEvent.MemberUp) });
        //_clientActor = ActorSystemRefs.ClientActor = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ClientActor()), "client");
        _clientActor = ActorSystemRefs.ClientActor = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create<ClientActor>(), "client");
        ClusterClientReceptionist.Get(Context.System).RegisterService(_clientActor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Re-subscribe on restart
    /// </summary>
    protected override void PostStop()
    {
        Cluster.Unsubscribe(Self);
    }

    protected override void OnReceive(object message)
    {
        if (message is ClusterEvent.MemberUp)
        {
            _log.Info("Cluster is ready. Able to begin jobs.");
            //ready to begin routing messages to back-end
            Become(Ready);
            Stash.UnstashAll();
        }
        else
        {
            Stash.Stash();
        }
    }

    protected void Ready(object message)
    {
            //Bunch of stuff here for processing messages that come in
    }

    public IStash Stash { get; set; }

}
```

### Server Code - /manager/client Actor

```
class ClientActor : ReceiveActor, ILoggingFSM, ILogReceive
    {
        private readonly ILoggingAdapter _log = Logging.GetLogger(Context);

        /// <summary>
        /// Need to subscribe to cluster changes
        /// </summary>
        protected override void PreStart()
        {
            _log.Info("Client Actor Starting ...");
        }

        public ClientActor()
        {
            Ready();
        }

        private void Ready()
        {
            _log.Info("Receive Actor has moved to Ready");
            _log.Info("Client Ref is " + Context.Self.Path.ToString());

            Receive<OrderMessage>(message =>
                {
                    var mes = message as OrderMessage;

                    //New Order Received
                    if (mes.State == OrderStates.New)
                    {
                        _log.Info("Order " + mes.OrderID.ToString() + " received");
                        //Send Order Message back to client router with ACK State
                        Sender.Tell(new OrderMessage(mes.ClientID, mes.OrderID, OrderStates.Acknowledged, mes.Side, mes.Symbol, mes.Price, mes.Quantity));
                        //send ordermessage manager for processing
                        ActorSystemRefs.ManagerActor.Tell(mes);
                    }
                    if (mes.State == OrderStates.Complete)
                    {
                        _log.Info("Order " + mes.OrderID.ToString() + " Completed");
                        //Send Order Message back to client router to indicate completed with Final Price
                        Context.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://ClientSystem@localhost:8091/user/ordertracker").Tell(mes);
                    }
                });

            Receive<OrderTrack>(message =>
                {
                    //Working Update Received, Should Forward Stats to Client Router
                });
        }
    }
```

Here is a snip of the wireshark I have running between the two. No packets are seeing until I refresh my RDP Window several seconds after I attempt to send the Message (7:46:24)

[Wireshark Screep Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJqwQ.jpg)

Comment: I have doubts about your configured `akka.actor.provider`, the doc says it should be `Either one of "local", "remote" or "cluster" or the FQCN of the ActorRefProvider to be used` but you have `"Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster"` which is neither...

Comment: "cluster" is the shorthand version for "Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster" from everything I have seen

Comment: If I leave out provider I get the below. It seems the remote/cluster provider is fine if the Actor is attempting to send remotely. It cannot even attempt without having that initialized I believe. ERROR: 2017-08-30 11:25:33.0696 Akka.Cluster.Tools.Client.ClusterClient 5 Sending GetContacts to [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://ClientSystem/deadLetters), Path(/system/receptionist)]] 
    2017-08-30 11:25:33.0696 Akka.Actor.DeadLetterActorRef 4 Message GetContacts from akka://ClientSystem/user/ordertracker/crouter to akka://ClientSystem/deadLetters was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.

Comment: As a test, I changed from longhand to "cluster" and also just "remote" for provider and I see the exact same logs/behavior.

Comment: It looks like your client doesn't know where cluster receptionist could be found. Have you populated `akka.cluster.client.initial-contacts = []` list in your HOCON config?

Comment: Yes, initial contacts is populated.

Comment: Yes, section is printed in Client Debug logs:         initial-contacts : ["akka.tcp://NGOMSCluster@10.20.223.45:8092/system/receptionist"]